# How to pass auth token while connecting to socket.io using postman?

Tags: dart, websocket, socket.io, postman

This is how I've been adding my auth creds (map) to a socket in socket.io:

```
socket = io(
    url.toString(),
    OptionBuilder()
        .setTransports(['websocket'])
        .disableAutoConnect()
        .enableForceNew()
        .enableForceNewConnection()
        .setAuth({"token": token})
        .build());
```

Although there is no such auth option while connecting using POSTMAN.
I tried setting a "auth" header and then passing the token there, but that did not work either. Then I tried to send a "auth" header with {"token" : TOKEN}, that did not work.

Answer (score 5):

Now days the object auth is not supported by Postman yet, insted you must use the raw websocket and send the message 40{"token":"123"} who is the package format to send a connection with token.

[Raw socket postman example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8tWG.png)

Here is a discussion about how to send authentication paylod
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/discussions/4072

Here is information about socket.io protocol
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

If want to use socketIO postman.
instead of saving token in auth,
you can send with header.

`const token = socket.handshake.headers.access_token;`

Postman request

[image: 1]

Comment: but how do you pass it to auth though?

Answer (score 1):

Applications often use tokens in auth, but postman does not support it.
You put the token in the postman header and your server gets the token in this way:

```
const Authorization = socket.handshake.auth?.token || socket.handshake.headers?.token;
```